# javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION not found

Tags: java, spring, content-disposition

I am developing a web application and when I try to use

```
javax.ws.rs.core.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION
```

I receive the following error:

> CONTENT_DISPOSITION cannot be resolved or is not a field.

Please help me to resolve this issue!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This means you don't have JAX-RS libraries in your classpath. Are you using Maven for dependency or something else ? You need to add a depdency to JAX-RS.

Comment: I can use the other constants of HttpHeaders. This is the only constant that I cannot use. I am using Maven for dependecy as far as I know. I haven't set up the project and the person who did it is not here to ask him.

Comment: Then show the code where you are using it and whar dependency you use.

Answer (score 2):

This is likely because of confusion between two different versions of the HttpHeaders class: JDK 7 and Java EE 6. The [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html#CONTENT_DISPOSITION) for JDK 1.7 show `CONTENT_DISPOSITION` as being defined; however, a Java EE 6 project does not have the `CONTENT_DISPOSITION` constant, as shown in its [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.html) and in the source code for [JSR 311](https://github.com/javaee/jsr311/blob/master/src/jsr311-api/src/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.java).

Here is a JDK 1.7 project that depends on the Java EE 6 library. Notice that the IDE cannot find the constant:

[image: Invalid import]

This is confirmed by the autocomplete listing, which matches the API for Java EE 6:

[image: Available imports]

There are a few options available:

- Hard-code the text string, `"Content-Disposition"`.
- Use the [JAX-RS API](https://github.com/jax-rs/api/blob/master/jaxrs-api/src/main/java/javax/ws/rs/core/HttpHeaders.java), instead of JSR 311.
- Use Google's version of [HttpHeaders](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-http-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/http/HttpHeaders):

```java
import static com.google.common.net.HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION;
```